# How can I filter a union by presence or absence of a property

Tags: typescript

I have a type `IResponse` for an API response joined by OR  which varies depending on a url search parameter.

here is how I intend to use it

```
const data1 = await request<E<"aaa">>('/api/data/1?type=aaa');
const data2 = await request<E<"bbb">>('/api/data/1?type=bbb');

function request<T>(
  url: string
): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url, config)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data as T);
}
```

```
//index.ts

import {
  paths,
} from "./autoGeneratedTypes";

type IResponse =
  paths["/api/data/{id}"]["get"]["responses"]["200"]["content"]["application/json"];

export type E<T extends "aaa" | "bbb"> = T extends "aaa"
  ? Omit<IResponse, "ca">
  : Pick<IResponse, "ca">;

export type F = E<"aaa">["bb"];
```

I get an error at `Pick<IResponse, "ca">` saying `Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'`

I do not want to directly reference schemas `C` or `B` as their schema names can change, so I need a type which will extract the right type for the api response from `IResponse`.

```
//autoGeneratedTypes.ts
/**
 * This file was auto-generated by openapi-typescript.
 * Do not make direct changes to the file.
 */

export interface paths {
  "/api/data/{id}": {
    /** @description get the data */
    get: {
      responses: {
        /** @description Retrieved the data successfully */
        200: {
          content: {
            "application/json": components["schemas"]["D"];
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}

export interface components {
  schemas: {
    D: components["schemas"]["C"] | components["schemas"]["B"];
    C: {
      ca: components["schemas"]["B"][];
    };
    B: {
      ba: string;
      bb: components["schemas"]["A"][];
    };
    A: {
      aa: string;
      ab: string | null;
    };
  };
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDLAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDc6mWARvkWVVAD5TkCuANr7TQBfQelCQoAIQTI6UBnkIkKNOQyawA2gF1BI9GPDQAwjNQYoAY0WS9otOOgARGac62DaCAA8wAe2JgKEcoAFEAHgAVKB9gCHIAEwIoACIcLBSOVPUGFIA+GWjY+KTU9JS5AH4oAHkAW1JgcKcAGlTrfLl8AAVSSwBrZraUjrz7H39A4KMoAFksMDAVAgB1RoALY25iYnjLEBkItJx8zRT1FN10IA

Comment: 1st code block is how I intend to use type `E` and is for context.
The error is in the 2nd code block which I need help fixing.

Comment: This is still unclear. Are you just trying to resolve `D` to either `B` or `C`?

Comment: yes I am trying to resolve `D` to either `B` or `C`

Comment: Then where does `E` come into it?

Comment: `E` helps to resolve it, as I cannot directly refer `B` or `C`

Comment: Why can't you directly refer to `B` or `C`? You've said in your question you don't want to. Why not?

Comment: These types are generated from openapi spec. We refer to the generated types using the `url` as keys. So we can refer to D using `url`, and `C` and `D` are schema names which can change. So every time the schema names change we will have to change our code. So we prefer to just use url as keys to refer to types from the automatically generated types. Maybe I'll update the question to reflect this context.

Comment: ① The title to this question isn't great; your question should be "how can I do XXX", not "there's an error in my failed attempt", since that doesn't let anyone know at a glance what you're trying to do.  Could you please [edit] the title to reflect what you're trying to do, like "How can I filter a union by presence or absence of a property"? ② I guess you want `Extract` and `Exclude` instead of `Pick` and `Omit`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WyoVZN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) and [`Exclude<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility types to filter [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  These types take a union type `T`, and either keep (for `Extract`) or reject (for `Exclude`) any members of `T` that are assignable to `U`.

In your case it looks like you want:

```
type E<T extends "aaa" | "bbb"> =
  T extends "aaa" ? Exclude<IResponse, { ca: any }> : Extract<IResponse, { ca: any }>
```

which produces

```
export type F = E<"aaa">["bb"]; // okay
/* type F = {
    aa: string;
    ab: string | null;
}[] */
```

as desired.

Your version didn't work because the [`Pick<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [`Omit<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility types filter the *properties* of the `T` type, and do not work well when `T` is a union since they do not distribute over unions in `T`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQEsB2CxwGYEMDGYSACrggBYDOSA3qEkgEQD0uUKzAJmbszSpwC+jAFy16DJMwBU0pAAFOYSvjgooCFDDRIA5mGQUi3BLiTTmEhvoRi6ISZLjLYaSsrtXHU2QqUq1DS0dACUDNTAANzBOJCMkEzNKAFd8QkpKbGSAG2yAT3NLB28GACYABnLPYpKGfG1MDGra70Y2KGyUfDJg5gArSm1RJABhGABbVzAMSgBtRhVyMHHcSkYAXXmAEQ2Abi8SwX2a7yODpDOTy4ZLwVBQSFhEVAwsPEJRiamZ8WLF5dWzUkWzEY0m2mmCDmC3wSxWa02jBGGyQAB9PuC0JDof94Rt5gAhPZeEZAxzdUFfCEzea41b4xhEzbrY6Oa6SAlkyQAI1wYkoCDUaF0rO83O5lMx2NpsIBCPmAEF8SyvOyGAquQxcHykAKhSLzrgJbrBehdGikGgctlRTdRbd7iAEHkoEQAJJhSiudxIAC8ElIFGhrHYXB4fAEwkRNgZzi92nc8sYFXKDPqrwwDPanW6mm0-UGaGJIAe0HghhdRAAogAeAAqSEgjU41Da2sYFsY4u5jAAfH6JA2m9MW0xtbgOwB+JBViD4bLJJQ1j0uBNgAA0tCQFKQuDQBUE-bEs8FBAQy893o3W53e4Pvcdj3LcUrSAAYn6ZzW2xPe-NxXsUjMEgMAANa4HkoAyC+rrvp+9iONq-KmsKtq7saepmhaVq5McgizOshSOkAA)